# Compare two dataframe columns for matching percentage

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, compare

I want to compare a data frame of one column with another data frame of multiple columns and return the header of the column having maximum match percentage.

I am not able to find any match functions in pandas. First data frame first column :

```
cars
----   
swift   
maruti   
wagonor  
hyundai  
jeep
```

First data frame second column :

```
bikes
-----
RE
Ninja
Bajaj
pulsar
```

one column data frame :

```
words
---------
swift 
RE 
maruti
waganor
hyundai
jeep
bajaj
```

Desired output :

```
100% match  header - cars
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) function of pandas DataFrame. Assuming df is your first dataframe and words is a list :

```
In[1]: (df.isin(words).sum()/df.shape[0])*100
Out[1]:
cars     100.0
bikes     20.0
dtype: float64
```

You may need to lowercase strings in your df and in the words list to avoid any casing issue.

Comment: Nice one liner! However, for me it only works if ``words`` is a list. I think when you pass a pandas Series to ``isin``, it will try to match both the index and the value. So the Series and the DataFrame would have to be ordered the same way for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can first get the columns into lists:

```
dfCarsList = df['cars'].tolist()
dfWordsList = df['words'].tolist()
dfBikesList = df['Bikes'].tolist()
```

And then iterate of the list for comparision:

```
numberCars = sum(any(m in L for m in dfCarsList) for L in dfWordsList)
numberBikes = sum(any(m in L for m in dfBikesList) for L in dfWordsList)
```

The higher number you can use than for your output.

Answer (score 1):

Construct a `Series` using [`numpy.in1d`](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) and [`ndarray.mean`](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.mean.html) then call the [`Series.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) and [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html) methods:

```
# Setup
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'cars': {0: 'swift', 1: 'maruti', 2: 'waganor', 3: 'hyundai', 4: 'jeep'}, 'bikes': {0: 'RE', 1: 'Ninja', 2: 'Bajaj', 3: 'pulsar', 4: np.nan}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'words': {0: 'swift', 1: 'RE', 2: 'maruti', 3: 'waganor', 4: 'hyundai', 5: 'jeep', 6: 'bajaj'}})

match_rates = pd.Series({col: np.in1d(df1[col], df2['words']).mean() for col in df1})

print('{:.0%} match header - {}'.format(match_rates.max(), match_rates.idxmax()))
```

[out]

```
100% match header - cars
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with a function that returns a tuple `(column_name, match_percentage)` for the column with the maximum match percentage. It accepts a pandas dataframe (bikes and cars in your example) and a series (words) as arguments.

```
def match(df, se):
    max_matches = 0
    max_col = None
    for col in df.columns:
        # Get the number of matches in a column
        n_matches = sum([1 for row in df[col] if row in se.unique()])
        if n_matches > max_matches:
            max_col = col
            max_matches = n_matches
    return max_col, max_matches/df.shape[0]
```

With your example, you should get the following output.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Cars'] = ['swift', 'maruti', 'wagonor', 'hyundai', 'jeep']
df['Bikes'] = ['RE', 'Ninja', 'Bajaj', 'pulsar', '']
se = pd.Series(['swift', 'RE', 'maruti', 'wagonor', 'hyundai', 'jeep', 'bajaj'])

In [1]: match(df, se)
Out[1]: ('Cars', 1.0)
```